# Knockout ko.mappings.fromJS not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to use knockout mapping, but it isn't working as I expected.
Here I created simpliest fiddle i can and it's not working.

Am I missing something?

https://jsfiddle.net/p48d11j5/1/

```
function Model(){
    var self = this;

    self.Id = ko.observable(0);
    self.Name = ko.observable("Default");
    self.Visible = ko.observable(false);
    self.Items = ko.observableArray([]);
}

function ModelItem(){
    var self = this;

    self.Id = ko.observable(0);
    self.Name = ko.observable("Default item name")
}

var m = new Model();

ko.mapping.fromJS({
    Id:1,
    Name: "Test",
    Visible: true,
    Items: [
    {
        Id:1,
        Name:"First"
    },
    {
        Id:2,
        Name:"Second"
    }
  ]
}, m);

ko.applyBindings(m);
```

*edit: I am working with nested arrays, so I added array*

*edit2: I want have models "typed" to use functions or ko.computed properties of them*

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do ? https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/21/

Comment: @Matt.kaaj Yes, this is it, but i wanted to use mapping plugin, so i don't need passing data this way.

Comment: if you would like to use `mapping plugin` check out my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call `ko.mapping.fromJS` with two arguments :
    `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappedObject)` the second argument is a `mappedObject` which is already created.Then the second argument will be taken as a `viewModel` not `options`.


All you have to do is: ko.mapping.fromJS(data, **{}**, viewModel) - this one puts your data in your model.

```
ko.mapping.fromJS({
    Id:1,
    Name: "Test",
    Visible: true,
    Items: [{Id: 1, Name: "First"}, {Id: 2, Name: "Second"}]
  }, {} ,m);  // pass the second argument as an empty object.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var m = ko.mapping.fromJS({
    Id:1,
  Name: "Test",
  Visible: true,
  Items: [
    {
        Id:1,
      Name:"First"
    },
    {
        Id:2,
      Name:"Second"
    }
  ]
}, new Model());

ko.applyBindings(m);
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/p48d11j5/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can give something like this a try, using the mapping plugin to set up your default state as well as to apply updates:

```
// Set up the initial model.
var model = ko.mapping.fromJS({
    Id: 0,
    Name: "Default",
    Visible: false,
    Items: []
});

ko.applyBindings(model);

// Map new data from the "server"...
var model = ko.mapping.fromJS({
    Id:1,
    Name: "Test",
    Visible: true,
    Items: [
    {
        Id:1,
        Name:"First"
    },
    {
        Id:2,
        Name:"Second"
    }
    ]
}, model);

// ...or directly manipulate the model.
model.Id(2);
model.Items.push({Id: 3, Name: "Third"});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3evtx022/

Comment: Thank you for response. But I want models have "typed", so i can use functions or ko.computed properties on them.
Is there any way? Or should I just give up?